# Setting ETW event level in service fabric tracing

Tags: trace, azure-service-fabric, azure-diagnostics

When you create a service fabric application project using visual studio, you get an implementation of EventSource (called ServiceEventSource). For example, here is one of the method implementation:

```
    private const int ServiceRequestStopEventId = 6;
    [Event(ServiceRequestStopEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "Service request '{0}' finished", Keywords = Keywords.Requests)]
    public void ServiceRequestStop(string requestTypeName)
    {
        WriteEvent(ServiceRequestStopEventId, requestTypeName);
    }
```

As you can see, this method has Event attribute which has Level argument set.

1. Where would I set that Level argument value?
2. I am thinking that setting this Level's argument value will show how much output gets generated. Am I correct?
3. Can I modify this Level argument value dynamically at run time and at will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set `Level` only in the `Event` attribute.
2. The amount of output getting generated depends on consumers of logs. If there are no consumers or listeners, event will not be generated at any level. We can say that level depends on amount of output, but only if there are consumers of such event.
3. No, you can't modify the level dynamically. To do this, you could have two methods with the same signature and different levels.

You can find all the interesting information about ETW and its configuration [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-44-08-22/_5F00_EventSourceUsersGuide.docx).

Comment: If WAD is my consumer and I would like to capture, lets say, all informational messages only, how would I configure the WAD to listen for informational messages only?

Comment: @Raghu unfortunately, seems like there is no way to log only particular level. Instead, you can specify *minimum* level. Look here: [section Add to extensions array of VirtualMachineProfile, EtwManifestProviderConfiguration, parameter scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/). You can find more info on parameters in [xml schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634522.aspx).

Comment: You pointed me to the flag that I am after in WAD configuration: scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The code just indicates information about the ETW events it generates. Setting the level indicates in which category the event will be put. It doesn't configure whether the event is output. The logging tool determines whether it's logged or not. And you can usually change that level in the logging tool at run time.

Some useful links:

1. Configure WAD:
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/
2. Use Elastic Search
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostic-how-to-use-elasticsearch/
3. Use OMS to analyse the events.
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/log-analytics-service-fabric/
4. Use Service Profiler (Actors)
   https://www.azureserviceprofiler.com/

Comment: I understand that the attribute is merely a setting at what level it will write the event. I also looked at the WAD configuration. I am not looking at the log data in real time but only after certain period. I do understand that it is a pub/sub architecture. In the WAD article, I have not seen any level information that will capture the events. In particular, I looked at the section for 'IaaSDiagnostics'. It does not have any level information. In addition, the service profiler is only seem to be for azure web apps and not for micro-services hosted in service fabric cluster.